# Why is a snake tied around the belly of lord Shri Ganesha

Tags: ganesha

I have seen many idols and pictures of Lord Shri Ganesha and have noticed in many idols that a snake is tied around his belly. What is the significance of that snake. Is it an ornament or does it have any story behind it

[image: The snake is tied around his belly]